# QuickSort Partitioning pivot anomaly

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, partitioning, array-algorithms

Consider an Array A={1,2,0,4,5} how do I sort this using quick sort by taking the middle element as pivot in the partitioning process ?..The pivot becomes '0' and so in this array, there is no  valid left pointer present. How isthis anomaly be solved ? Can anybody explain me the step by step working of this algorithm ?

Comment: Quicksort works fine in that case, although it's performance will suffer if every pivot selected is at one end or the other. I doubt you'll get better explanations of quicksort here than any of the myriad explanations out there, including [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Comment: After the partition you will have `A = {0, 2, 1, 4, 5}` then you need to recursively sort the ranges [-1, 0) (empty) and [1, 5).

Comment: Taking the median of first, middle and last element avoids this, so it's a slight improvement.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a series of improvements to the pick a pivot algorithm over the years, the first used the last element as the pivot, soon improved to pick a random element, this prevents malicious attacks on the algorithm, then pick the media of x random.

A [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians), which split the elements between 30%/70% and 70%/30% thus always guaranteeing a minimum of 30% progress, a good [article](https://rcoh.me/posts/linear-time-median-finding/) explaining this, which has recently (2017) been improved by [Alexandrescu et al](http://erdani.com/research/sea2017.pdf) by an adaptive algorithm.